# how to parse the following date format Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) in java

Tags: java, date

I am getting the date in the format `Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530` (India Standard Time). I have to convert it to sql date of format `dd/MM/yyyy`. Please help.

I tried below code but did not help

```
Date date = new java.sql.Date(
(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zz (zzzz)").parse("Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"))
.getTime());
```

Comment: I think that main problem is with part of string `(India Standard Time)`. Try to cut it off

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and either `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`; all three are  from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like below, also refer here for [Java SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String time = "Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = inputFormat.parse(time);
        System.out.println(date);

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
    }
```

**output**

```
Mon Nov 09 00:00:00 IST 2015
09/11/2015
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, this helps but the date obj is of type java.util.Date, the final value that i need is in java.sql.Date for the db2 query where condition.

Comment: @user1374266 i think you can convert it now from java date to sql one.

Comment: Thanks a lot , got it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1374266 Welcome..!! Keep helping others as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

Since your date-time string has timezone information, parse it into `ZonedDateTime` which you can convert to other *java.time* types and if required, format into the desired formats.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
        
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                        .appendPattern("E MMM d uuuu H:m:s")
                                        .appendLiteral(" ")
                                        .appendZoneId()
                                        .appendPattern("X")
                                        .appendLiteral(" ")
                                        .appendLiteral("(")
                                        .appendGenericZoneText(TextStyle.FULL)
                                        .appendLiteral(')')
                                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfInput);
        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);
        
        // To LocalDate, LocalDateTime etc.
        LocalDate localDate = odt.toLocalDate();
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(localDate);
        System.out.println(localDateTime);
        
        // Get the formatted string
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtfOutput.format(localDate);
        System.out.println(formatted);
        
        // In UTC
        odt = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-11-09T00:00+05:30
2015-11-09
2015-11-09T00:00
09/11/2015
2015-11-08T18:30Z
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Support for `OffsetDateTime` in JDBC:

Starting with JDBC 4.2, you can use `OffsetDateTime` directly in your code e.g.

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, odt);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

The support for *java.time* API in JDBC Java SE 8 (JDBC 4.2) came without requiring any public JDBC API changes. The `setObject` and `getObject` methods support *java.time* types as per the following mapping:

[image]

**Note for PostgreSQL™:** `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant` and `OffsetTime` / `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` are not supported. Also, the `OffsetDateTime` instances need to be in UTC (have offset 0).

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Good to have a modern answer to this question (’twas about time). Thank you. I’d probably go with `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx (zzzz)", Locale.ROOT)`. I might also parse both into an `OffsetDateTime` and a `ZonedDateTime` and check that the offsets agree, for validation.

Comment: The format, `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx (zzzz)` would be limited to `GMT` but the parser in this answer will work also for `UTC` (e.g. `Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 UTC+0530 (India Standard Time)` without any change.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with something like this right now, and this is my solution:

```java
 String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(timestamp.toDate()).toString();
```